# How to upload a image into server folder using fileupload controle in asp.mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Could you please tell me how can i save the image into server path image folder when i upload a image using file upload controle in asp.mvc3 .please help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View：

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    { %>
        <div class="uploadfiles">
            <p><input type="file" name="files" /></p>
        </div>

        <a href="#add" id="additem">Add files</a><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Yes" />
<% } %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#additem').live('click', function () {
        $('.uploadfiles').append($("<p><input type='file' name='files' /></p>"));
    });
</script>
```

Controller：

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection[] form)
{
    for (int fileIndex = 0; fileIndex < Request.Files.Count; fileIndex++)
    {
        //let upload file to App_Data folder
        Request.Files[fileIndex].SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/App_Data/" + Request.Files[fileIndex].FileName));
    }
    return View();
}
```

---

It's depend the name of textbox, for example if there is an input in View like:

```
<input name="yourname" type="text" />
```

then you can get the value in Controller use:

```
var textBoxValue = formCollection["yourname"].ToString()
```

Comment: Thank You so much Maidot it is working fine what i'm expecting.How Can i get textbox values using FormCollection[] form ?

Comment: Ok ,Thank you again i'm using FormCollection objformCollection to get textbox values now it is working fine ,U have done good job thank you so much......

Comment: I am so glad that can help you~ :)

Comment: Hi can you give any idea how to bind the dropdownlist from database in mvc please...

Comment: Can you give me the datastructure(Model) of the data you want to bind so I can help you, or some code more better~

Comment: i have two tables both are having the relationship.In view model i inherit (Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<mobilemvc.Models.tb1_ad>" %>)  the 1st table data ,now want Bind the 2nd table(tb_table2) data in to drop down  ....

Comment: OK I see~ but that's hard to explain in comment, I will post to my blogspot and tell you :)

Comment: Here is the basic way to use DropDownListFor: [link](http://maidot.blogspot.com/2011/04/aspnet-mvc-viewdropdownlistfor.html) . if you have problems, let me know~ :)

Comment: Thank you maidot, i found a another link it is working fine http://ittecture.wordpress.com/2009/05/10/tip-of-the-day-208-asp-net-mvc-populating-dropdownlists-using-linq-to-sql/. Thank you so much to give a replay.....

Comment: excellent! thank you to give me that link, a better way, thank you ^_^